# Redis Cookbook Chat Recipe

Tags: node.js, redis, chat, publish-subscribe, cookbook

I am a new starter to Node.Js and Redis. I got the Redis cookbook and was trying out the Chat client & Server recipe.

I was wondering if anybody got the code to work or if there is some bug in the code.

I dont see where the sent messages from the client get invoked on the server.

Any help would be great.

Regards,
Tom

Client Code:

```
<?php

?> 

<html>
<head>
<title></title>


<script src="http://192.168.0.118:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>


var socket = io.connect('192.168.0.118',{port:8000});

socket.on('message', function(data){
alert(data);
//var li = new Element('li').insert(data);
//$('messages').insert({top: li});
});


</script>

</head>

<body>

<ul id="messages">
<!-- chat messages go here -->
</ul>

<form id="chatform" action="">
<input id="chattext" type="text" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
<script>

$('#chatform').submit(function() {
socket.emit('message', 'test'); //$('chattext').val());
$('chattext').val(""); // cleanup the field
return false;
});

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Server Code:

```
var http = require('http');
io = require('socket.io');

redis = require('redis');
rc = redis.createClient();
//rc1 = redis.createClient();

rc.on("connect",function(){
rc.subscribe("chat");
console.log("In Chat Stream");
});

rc.on("message",function (channel,message){

 console.log("Sending hope: " + message);
 //rc1.publish("chat","hope");
 socketio.sockets.emit('message',message);
});

server = http.createServer(function(req,res){

res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'text/html'});
res.end('<h1>hello world</h1>');

});

server.listen(8000);

var socketio = io.listen(server);
```

Comment: This is a very general question. Care to post more about the specific problems you are seeing getting this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not listening for any connect / message events from socket.io.. try something like

```
socketio.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
   console.log("Got connection");
   socket.on('message', function(msg) {
       rc1.publish("chat", msg);
   });
});
```

You'll need to uncomment your `rc1` up there, you will need that second redis connection

Comment: I saw this post but did not see the solution. Am a little stuck

Comment: Ok looks like you arn't listening for any events on the socket.io front, i edited my answer to reflect a suggestion